# How to get the data programatically using Webclient / HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

[image]

I wanted to download the data from https://eauction.ccmc.gov.in/frm_scduled_items.aspx using the date listed in the dropdown.

```
    private async Task Cbetest()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://eauction.ccmc.gov.in");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridedit$ctl14$ctl02","17/02/2016")
        });
            var result = await client.PostAsync("/frm_scduled_items.aspx", content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
        }
    }
```

I wanted to download the data shown in the above image

Comment: Okay. So you have some code, and you've stated a goal. But what problem are you facing? How does your code not perform as expected? You need to ask a clear question.

Comment: i'm not getting the content after selecting the date.
the above code returns only the list of dates not the actual data

Comment: look up html agility pack.

Comment: yeah but i'm not getting the content after selecting the date.

Comment: Are you sure the element (drop down) is not ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drp_auction_date ? Script actually uses that as argument to do post back.

Comment: sorry i'm quite new to these kind of data scrapping. please correct me if something wrong in the above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a little extra work to simulate a post to begin scraping against a ASP.NET WebForms application. Mostly, you're going to need to pass along valid ViewState and EventValidation parameters, which you can retrieve from an initial GET request.

I'm using the HTML Agility Pack to ease with parsing the initial response, I recommend you look into it if you're planning to scrape HTML.

The following seems to get the results you're looking for, though I haven't looked too deeply in the response HTML.

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://eauction.ccmc.gov.in");

    var initial = await client.GetAsync("/frm_scduled_items.aspx");

    var initialContent = await initial.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(initialContent);

    var viewState = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATE']").GetAttributeValue("value", string.Empty);
    var eventValidation = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id='__EVENTVALIDATION']").GetAttributeValue("value", string.Empty);

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>{
        {"__VIEWSTATE", viewState},
        {"__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation},
        {"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drp_auction_date", "17/02/2016"}
    });

    var res = await client.PostAsync("/frm_scduled_items.aspx", content);

    var resContent = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(resContent);
}
```

From there you'll want to parse the resulting table to get useful information. If you want to crawl through the DataGrid's pages, you're going to need to get updated EventValidation and ViewState values and simulate additional posts for each page.

Comment: thanks for your timely help. This helped me saving lot of time. Thanks once again.